# Eagerly Load Object Graph with EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have a fairly deep object graph and would like to eagerly load the entire graph.

I'm aware that I can eagerly load specific navigation properties using .Include().

However, that seems fragile (if I add a navigation property, I must also add an additional .Include) and requires (in my case) quite a few .Include() statements.

Is there a way to instruct EF to eagerly load the entire object graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must manually include every navigation property you want to eager load. EF doesn't provide any built in way to include all.

> However, that seems fragile (if I add a navigation property, I must
>   also add an additional .Include) and requires (in my case) quite a few
>   .Include() statements.

It is less fragile than automagic include of everything. Such feature would just cause too many problems because in many cases it would eager load navigation properties unexpectedly.

As a workaround you can create some custom extension method which will explore EF metadata of your entity types and add `Include` call for every navigation property in your graph.

There are [several proposed features](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/04/eager-loading-improvements-needed-in-ef/) for improving eager loading in EF. You can go through them, upvote features you see valuable or propose a new one.

Comment: Is this still the best way to load an entire object graph?  Have any of those proposed features seen the light of day?

Answer (score 0):

> However, that seems fragile (if I add a navigation property, I must also add an additional .Include) and requires (in my case) quite a few .Include() statements.

In order to keep all of the code to load the object graph in one place, I created an extension method that can be used from anywhere in the code

```
static public IQueryable<My> IncludeAll(this DbSet<My> parent)
{
    var include = parent
        .Include(p => p.CollA)
        .Include(p => p.CollB)
        .Include(p => p.CollC)
        .Include(p => p.CollD)
        .Include(p => p.CollE)
        .Include(p => p.CollF)
        .Include(p => p.Etc);

    return include;
}
```

Usage

```
var query = ctx.Mys.IncludeAll().Where(...);
```